# Printing a Linked List from Text Files: Output only print out one name - Java

Tags: java, list, printing

I have the following method written in Java. I intend it to read out the Scanner input text files of names, but at this moment, it would only take one name from the file and display it.

```
public class AssassinManager { 

private static class AssassinNode {
    private static String player; 
    private static String killer; 
    private AssassinNode next;
    private AssassinNode(String name){
        AssassinNode.player = name; 
        AssassinNode.killer = null; 
        this.next = null;
    } 
}// End of AssassinNode

private AssassinNode killring;  // the head of the kill ring linked list - first link
private AssassinNode graveyard; // the head of the graveyard linked list - second link 

/* AssasssinManager Constructor */
public AssassinManager(ArrayList<String> players){ 
    if (players == null || players.isEmpty()){ throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: ArryList is null/empty!"); }
    AssassinNode node = killring = new AssassinNode(players.get(0)); // create first node - for the killring
    for (int i = 1; i < players.size(); i++){ // Add a new node at the end of each killing 
        node.next = new AssassinNode(players.get(i));
        node = node.next;
    }
    System.out.println(players.size());
} // End of AssassinNode Constructor - Done 

/* Prints the names of the people in the kill ring */
public void printKillRing() {
    if(killring == null){ 
        return; // break out of printKillRing method when list is null
    }
    AssassinNode node = killring; 
    do {
        if (node.next == null) {
            System.out.println(node.player + " is stlaking " + node.player);
        } else 
            System.out.println(node.player + "-->");
        node = node.next;
    } while (node != null);
} // End of printKillRing
```

**Output:** 
Kelly-->Kelly-->Kelly is stalking Kelly

**Intended output:**
Kelly-->Jacob-->Ron

Comment: do you use any library? AssasinNode?

Comment: This is missing a lot of context. The source for `AssassinNode` would be very useful.

Comment: @Troncador I added the rest of the code in the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the AssassinNode class into,

```
private static class AssassinNode {
   private String player; 
   private String killer; 
   private AssassinNode next;

   private AssassinNode(String name){
       AssassinNode.player = name; 
       AssassinNode.killer = null; 
       this.next = null;
  } 
}// End of
```

removed the static keyword from player and killer

Comment: That worked! Thank you!! xx

Comment: you are welcome. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently AssassinNode has both a static and instance field of the name "player"? If not you need to change it be instance (just remove the static keyword from the field declaration). Once you've fixed that the following will (likely?) give you what you want.

```js
    public void printKillRing(){
        if(killring == null){ 
            return; // break out of printKillRing method when list is null
        }
        AssassinNode node = killring; 
        do {
            if (node.next == null){
                System.out.println(node.player);
            } else 
                System.out.print(node.player + "-->"); // print the current element 
            node = node.next;
            
        } while (node != null);
    } // End of printKillRing
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, the output was the same as my previous function.